# Implementing cookies on a dismissible slide-in panel with AMP

Tags: wordpress, cookies, amp-html, amp-bind

I'm implementing a slide-in-on-scroll newsletter signup form on our site, which is built as AMP-native.

I added a button that hides the div on tap using amp-bind, but I'm struggling to get my head around how to save the closed state with cookies/localStorage in AMP.

I've gone through the favorite button example code - https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/favorite_button/ (as recommended here on SE), but I don't see how it relates to this particular use-case, especially with the use of amp-list.

Based on what I've read and few examples I found the credentials="include" attribute is needed, as is a valid CORS json endpoint and an auto generated client id appended to the endpoint url using AMPs variable substitution, but I'm not sure how to put it all together.

I took a stab hacking something together using the favorite button example, but the tutorial doesn't say much about how to setup the CORS endpoint and that particular example is for storing multiple likes to a single endpoint, as apposed to storing a specific users viewing preferences.

Here is my rough (poking-around-in-the-dark) stab at the code:

```
<form method="post"
id="side-newsletter-wrap"
action-xhr="/prefs&clientId=CLIENT_ID(prefs)"
target="_top"
on="submit:AMP.setState({
        showSideNewsletter: !showSideNewsletter
    });
    submit-error:AMP.setState({
        showSideNewsletter: !showSideNewsletter
    });">
    <button on="tap:side-newsletter-wrap.hide" class="close-button"><i     
    class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    <amp-list width="320"
        height="360"
        credentials="include"
        items="."
        single-item
        src="/prefs&clientId=CLIENT_ID(prefs)">
        <template type="amp-mustache">
        {{#.}}
            <?php winefolly_load_fragment('newsletter-embed'); ?>
        {{/.}}
        {{^.}}{{/.}}
        </template>
    </amp-list>
</form>
```

For the prefs endpoint, I'm guessing I'd need to register a new endpoint in WordPress that outputs simple array with the preferences?

Something along the lines of:

```
{
    showSideNewsletter: "true",
    winesIndexView: "grid",
    winesIndexSort: "title"
}
```

I also tried the amp-user-notification component (which has the closed state built in) but that felt a bit hacky and the newsletter embed code (via iframe) doesn't get loaded due to a known bug - https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/18995).

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You're right amp-user-notification is the correct approach. Is there a way to implement the newsletter form in AMP until the amp-iframe bug is fixed?

Another way is to use amp-access, which allows you to change the layout of the page on page load. You have to store the user preference server-side though using the READER_ID to identify the user. Storing this server-side is required as you might not be able to write cookies if the page is served from the AMP Cache due to ITP 2.0.

Comment: Hi Sebastian,
Thanks for the reply. Does that mean there isn't currently a way to save a users preference, like view (grid/list), sorting, order, etc? I tried getting the cookies working on our amp-list update, but couldn't find any relevant examples, so had to push it forward for the next update. 

As for the iframe not working in the amp-user-consent, the only work around I can think of would be to create a custom Klaviyo subscribe form, using their api. Just seems odd that there isn't an easy, consistent way to do this in amp.

Comment: Hi again,

Regarding setting cookies to save the users viewing preferences, I noticed that after I appended &clientId=CLIENT_ID(prefs) to my amp-list src url, the prefs cookie is actually being set. Is there not a way in AMP to do a conditional check to see whether the cookie has been set or not?

I can also see that there is an *amp-store* entry being added to the localStorage when the amp-user-notification is closed, so it seems that the ability to save the state is there.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: You can serve user-data server-side based on the reader id. Client-side might not work if the AMP page is served from an AMP Cache as you won't be able to write cookies due to ITP 2.0.

Comment: Hey Sebastian, Thanks for the heads up on ITP 2.0, I hadn't heard of that before. Do you know of any examples of saving user-data server-side? I managed to find [this help doc](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7486764?hl=en) about setting up the amp client id api, but that seems more related to ga tracking and I can't find any mention of using the reader id.

Comment: Hi @SebastianBenz, 

I've added the slide-in-right attribute to the amp-user-notification and it's sliding in, but I'm struggling to get it to only slide in when you get to the bottom of the page and slide out when you scroll back up.

I tried setting to data-margin-start to 80%, but that just stops the slide-in animation from working.
 
You can see an example of what I'm trying to implement 
[here](https://www.takealot.com) and our implementation [here](https://winefolly.staging.wpengine.com)

Should I rather be using amp-position-observer with amp-animation?

TIA